# Custom view renders only as a white box on Kindle Fire (works elsewhere)

Tags: android

I am using this library: https://github.com/veritas1/vertical-slide-color-picker, which works fine and is basically a custom view for selecting colours.

But when I integrate the slider into my main app, it works fine on all but one device so far.  For some reason on the Kindle it appears as a white rectangle, but on all my other devices works perfectly.

Does anyone have any idea why this could happen? If I use their standalone demo it works even on the kindle too, but when I move the code from that into my app then it stops working as described. I have tried it in relative layouts and linear layouts with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the widget needs its values set in XML and not in code, I had hacked in values via the java, once I stopped doing that, it began to work.